# How to escape abcd.com in order to not being displayed as hyperlink in e-mail body?

Tags: email, gmail, html

I am generating e-mails and in the e-mail body (html formatted) I need to include abcd.com but I need to escape it somehow to avoid gmail displaying it as a link (there's nothing at that address).

Any hints, please? Tried to google it but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to be able to reliably obfuscate a URL so that *all* mail clients do not see it as such without obfuscating it so far that the user will not understand it either.

You could try spacing everything out like `http :// www . example . com / dir / subdir / file ? qstring`. The only other way I can think of is to include the URL as an image if you are sending rich-text mail. Both these techniques though will trip anti-spam measures as trying to disguise URLs is one of the most obvious signs of spammer activity.

Comment: Also, embedding images is bad from accessibility point of view. Plain text can be viewed with big fonts, read aloud with voice synthesis etc.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but that's not good enough (I guess there's no solution). I rather kept just abcd without .com. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

include this text immediately after your link:

(Please DO NOT click. There is nothing on this address.)

Cheers